# Error en webpack

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, webpack, frontend

tuve un error al usar webpack, alguno sabe como puedo solucionarlo?
Otra cosa: que son los polyfill en webpack y para que sirven ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que te hacen falta ciertos módulos, algo que podrías intentar sería borrar la carpeta de `node_modules` y volver a instalar todo.

Comment: Pues te faltan un montón de módulos. Prueba haciendo un `npm install`. En cuanto a los polyfills, pues son paquetes que dan soporte a los navegadores más antiguos. Imagina que javascript saca una nueva función. Esta nueva función solo está presente en las nuevas versiones de los navegadores, pero no en las viejas versiones. Si todos los navegadores la tuvieran solo tendrías que llamar la función y ya está, pero en la realidad si tu llamas a esa función en un navegador viejo, pues no la tiene y explota.

Comment: Eso viene a resolver los polifills con webpack, digamos que "te empacan" el código de esa nueva funcionalidad, para darle soporte a los navegadores viejos. Cuando los navegadores viejos ven la función extraña, ya no dicen ¿Y eso que es? Sino que ven que le mandaron también un paquetico con el código de esa funcionalidad, entonces ya no explotan porque ya saben que hacerl.

Comment: Un clásico ejemplo, `IE` no soporta `array.includes` (entre muchas cosas que no soporta XD) pero bueno, para que la soporte, se le manda el [código de la función](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes?retiredLocale=it#polyfill). Eso es un polyfill y webpack lo hace automático en cuanto empaca tu código (dependiendo de tu configuración claro está).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.